# How to disable my parallax effect on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a webpage that utilizes parallax.  Here's the parallax code in CSS:

```
.parallaxOne {
    background-image: url("img.JPG");
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I'd like for that to be disabled when the user is on a mobile phone.  This is what I've done:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .parallaxOne {
        background-image: url("1.JPG");
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

I want a lot of other stuff to be changed as well, but I figure that'll follow after figuring this out.

I got this from another post:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  //stuff
}
```

It didn't quite solve my problem in this exact situation, but perhaps I'm using it wrong.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You can either set `background-attachment` back to its initial value of `scroll` for screens < 768 (`max-width: 768px`), or just put the `fixed` for only screens > 768 (`min-width: 768px`).